# How do I set the color of a JLabel using Java?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jlabel

I will be creating multiple `Jlabel` components upon a `JButton` click. I know how to create a label and set text inside but I want this label to have a color.

I only know how to change the color of a label if it has a name but an important part of my program is when I declare the labels, I don't have names for them as shown in the code below:

```
newPanel.add(new JLabel("jlabel text"), g);
```

How can I set the color of the label?

Comment: What you mean `I don't have names`. Create a local variable for the label, and do all actions on it you need to before adding it to the panel.

Comment: But will I be able to add multiple jLabels with different colors over time using the same name?

Comment: @Anon if I understand you correctly, you probably want a function that accepts both the color and text, and returns a new jlabel, that you can pass to `add` on the same line

Comment: @Anon Local variables only exist for the duration of the block (essentially from nearest `{` above it, till a matching `}`). The "same name" is only a temporary alias, and it doesn't have to refer to same object between multiple invocations.

Comment: @Anon You might have jumped into swing too early perhaps, I suggest you to read again about the basics.

Comment: You're right haha, but I am doing this for a school project where we get to chose want we're making, there is no going back now lol so I gotta do my best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(r,g,b);
```

Answer (score 3):

> I don't have names for them as shown in the code below:

```
newPanel.add(new JLabel("jlabel text"), g);
```

So give the label a name:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("label text");
label.setOpaque( true );
label.setBackground( Color.RED );
newPanel.add(label, g);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should assign the label to a variable so that you can perform additional operations on it:

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("jlabel text");
myLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color.RED);
newPanel.add(myLabel);
```

Now place this code in a function, such as an event handler for your button. Each time you click the button it creates a **new JLabel**. The name `myLabel` only refers to the current one that is being created. So yes, you can reuse the same name to refer to a different JLabel object. At a given moment, the name can only refer to one JLabel at a time.